# ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta en mongoose con el resultado que me devuelve otra consulta y mostrarlo en la vista?

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, sql, handlebars.js

¡Buenas tardes!

Tengo una duda con respecto a mongoose.

Estoy recogiendo los resultados de una consulta con find({});

La cual muestro en la vista con handlebars.

Esta consulta me devuelve un id de usuario, y ahora quiero recuperar el nombre del usuario basandome en su id.

Pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, ya que yo en handlebars, hago un each para mostrar los resultados anteriores, me muestra el id, pero no se como hacer otra consulta mas, para con ese resultado, buscar ese nombre por id.

Espero que me haya explicado bien, y muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Un saludo!

**EDIT 15/02/2019**

Tal y como me ha comentado Mauricio Contreras, voy a exponer mi problema de una forma mas elaborada, dejo mi anterior respuesta para dejar constancia de mi error, y si alguien quiere exponer una pregunta, se de cuenta de como no hacerlo.

Tengo dos modelos creados en mongoose.

User:

```
    const userSchema = new Schema({
    mode : {type: Number, required : true},
    name : {type : String, required : true},
    surname : {type : String, required : true},
    email : {type : String, required : true},
    phone : {type : Number, required : true},   
    community : {type : String, required : true},   
    city : {type : String, required: true},   
    password : {type : String, required: true},  
    instagram : {type : String},   
    facebook : {type : String},   
    twitter : {type : String},  
    portfolio : {type : String},   
    tutorial : {type : Boolean, default : true},   
    ban : {type : Boolean, default : false}   
   });
```

Y offers:

```
    const OffersSchema = new Schema ({
id_advisor : {type : String, required : true},
title : {type : String, required : true},
short_description : {type : String, required: true, max : 150},
description : {type : String, required: true},
price_max : {type : String, required : true},
start_date : {type : Date, default : date},
end_date : {type : Date, default : end_date},
finished : {type : Boolean, default : false},
id_user : {type : String},
paid : {type : Boolean, default: false},
city : {type : String, required: true},
transation_id : {type : String}
    });
```

En mi ruta, he realizado una consulta en la que pido todas las ofertas que contengan una ciudad en concreto, y que me las ordene en orden descendente por por fecha.

```
const resultOffers = await Offers.find({city : req.user.city}).sort({start_date: "desc"});
```

Despues, en mi vista, voy sacando esos resultados con #each, escrito en handlebars.

```
    {{#each resultOffers}}
```

De modo que tengo mis ofertas ya listadas. Ahora mi problema es el siguiente:

El modelo Offers, me devuelve un id_advisor, que es el _id del modelo User.

Mi pregunta es:
¿como puedo hacer otra consulta con los diferentes id_advisor que devuelve el each, para sacar el nombre del usuario?

Un ejemplo de como lo haría en PHP

```
$consult1 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE city = '$city' ORDER BY start_date DESC";

$result1 = mysql_query($consult1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) {

    $id_advisor = $row['id_advisor'};
    $consult2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id_advisor'";
    $result = mysq_query($consult2);

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) {

    $name = $row2['name'] // AQUI TENGO YA EL NOMBRE
}

}
```

No es la mejor forma, pero creo que queda bien explicado asi.

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano!

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, si tienes el código de cómo ejecutas tu consulta, y el modelo del documento al que ejecutas la consulta, trata de subirlo para poder ayudarte con tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Edito mi codigo con una idea de lo que quiero hacer, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Revisando tu código veo lo siguiente: la clave `id_advisor` de tu modelo `Offers` es un tipo `String` y no guarda ninguna relación con la colección `users`, sólo la que tu mencionas. Es decir, ¿cuando guardas un documento tipo `Offer` le pasas el `string` del `id` de un usuario? Creo que podrías mejorar eso convirtiendo esa clave del modelo `Offers` en una referencia a la colección `users`. Eso tiene más sentido.